# Displaying Controls a Specified number of times in View Using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I Have adults and children in my Session Variables

```
int x = (int)Session["adults"] + (int)Session["children"];
```

Now I want to Display This In my View using Razor Engine

MR_*----Name****_*_**----Gender_**__**(One Passenger Detail Row)

Condition:-The No of Passenger Details rows should be equal to x

How should I proceed Should I make a model for Passenger Details and generate a strongly Typed 
Razor View or proceed any other way If I make simple Html controls How to get their values 
in my controller action using Form Collection.How to Update this information in my database
Please provide any link, reference, hint.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this in your view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.PassengerCount; i++)
{
    <text>MR_</text>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Name)<text>_</text>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Gender)                    
}
```

your get controller could look like

```
public ActionResult PassengerList()
{
    ViewBag.PassengerCount = (int)Session["adults"] + (int)Session["children"];
    return View();
}
```

and have you post controller accept the list like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PassengerList(List<Passenger> passengers)
{
    //Code here
}
```

with a model like

```
public class Passenger() {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```